# Alternativen zum Verb „verpassen“

Tags: single-word-request

> Die Klinik, zu der ich fahre, ist unweit von zuhause. Ich denke darüber nach, eine Stunde früher dort hinzufahren, um den Termin nicht zu **verpassen**.

Was ist eine Alternative zum Tunwort *verpassen?*

Im Internetwörterbuch habe ich die passenden Verben zum Zusammenhang gefunden, nämlich:

> vergeben
>
> versäumen

Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: vergeben macht keinen Sinn hier. Btw. wenn die Klinik unweit von zuhause ist, ist sie sehr nah und man muss nicht früher fahren, weil man es mit Sicherheit pünktlich schafft.

Comment: Warum willst du eine Alternative? Das solltest du erklären. "Verpassen" ist genau das richtige Wort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*vergeben* ist unpassend. *versäumen* ist bei Terminen ein üblicher Ausdruck.

(Wenn die Klinik unweit von zuhause ist, warum sollte man eine Stunde früher hin fahren? *unweit* bedeutet *nicht weit*)

Man kann auch:

- zu einem Termin zu spät kommen
- nicht rechtzeitig kommen
- unpünktlich erscheinen